# Not returning JSON reponse in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, request

I have created a logic for an API where I used a function to check whether the request is POST. And if not, it should return an error.

`AuthController.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller {
private static function allowOneMethod($request, $allowed_method, $success_function){
    $method = $request->method();
    if ($method != $allowed_method){
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Method not Allowed.'], 405);
    } else{
        $success_function();
    }
}

public function register(Request $request)
{

    $this->allowOneMethod($request, 'POST', function() {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'It is a POST request.'], 200);
    });

}
...
```

`routes/api.php` looks like this:

```
Route::any('/register', 'AuthController@register');
```

But all that I see is just a blank response. **What could be the reason?**

Comment: You're not returning anything from register.

Comment: But what do I need to return??? All that I need to return is up..

Comment: Why not route post requests in the routes file itself?

Comment: You have a few problems.  Returning in the closure doesn't return anything from register.

Comment: yeah. I tried returning some response. It returns it even if it is get request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not return your `allowOneMethod()` method back

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
// you need to return your method value 
    return $this->allowOneMethod($request, 'POST', function() {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'It is a POST request.'], 200);
    });

}
```